# Error while installation

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, uninstall

I am trying to install a software(*Bitnami Trac Stac*) on Windows 7. But it fails with following errors.

[image]

Actually I had this software installed previously but accidentally some of the files  including the un-installation files were accidentally deleted and now when I try to re install this software it fails.

Any idea how I can resolve these errors ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Disclosure: I'm a member of the BitNami team)

Try opening a Command Prompt, executing the command `set` and checking if there are any references to Python in the output.

We have detected an issue that appears when you have PYTHON_PATH and/or PYTHON_HOME environment variables (either because there is another Python installed or because it was in the past).

As a workaround so you can install Trac while we fix this:

- In a Command Prompt, run:

  ```
  set PYTHONPATH=
  ```

  and

  ```
  set PYTHONHOME=
  ```
- Drag the installer to the Command Prompt and hit Enter to execute it.

Comment: thanks this solved the installation issue but in the browser interface, no admin tab is shown as it was there in my previous installation. How can I get it back ?

Comment: Are you logged in? If you are, could you post a screenshot?